# What to do about an ANN producing completely different results?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, deep-learning, grid-search

I'm trying to train an artificial neural network and I know the question has been asked before about why the results vary and the answer is down the initialization of the weights being random.

I'm currently trying to do some grid search to tune parameters but I'm finding that I'm getting very different results on the exact same parameter searches.

My question is what is best practice for tuning hyperparameters? I was thinking one way would be to lock the randomseed but I'm afraid if I lock my random seed and just tune that way, it's just down to luck if i pick a good seed or not that's able to find an absolute minima.

Is the way forward then to just run it several times and find the best range of results and then use those weights going forward? (If so, does anyone know how to do that? I'm using Keras via the sklearn wrapper is `KerasRegressor`)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Happy to provide code samples if needed!

Answer (score 0):

Use cross validation to evaluate your results out of sample. Choose the best model of all evaluated models. Additionally, you should have a test set for final performance estimation.

Don't worry about the random initialization weights worry about overfiting.

Comment: every cross validation produces vastly different results b/c of the initialized weights

Comment: If you are not satisfied with your validation performance you may not have enough training data and I would recommend a simpler model.

Comment: Different cross validation results can be expected and are no reason for concern. However, because you have high variance for the cv performance estimates model selection will overfit.